# Dúvida sobre ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Minha dúvida está em saber se este meu codigo está correto.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#fechar").click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  String lista_Cont = $(this).attr('<?php include "listaUsuario2.php";?>');
                  $("#lista").load(this.lista_Cont);
                });
            });
```

A função dele é, quando eu fechar o modal, onde eu utilizado para cadastrar um novo usuário, ele recarregue o conteúdo atualizado novamente, porem é na mesma pagina onde já esta.

Eu tenho uma pagina de Admin, onde eu clico em cadastrar e vou em usuários, o sistema em Ajax retorna apenas o conteúdo do meio alterado, neste conteúdo vem o código onde eu listo todos os usuários já cadastrados e dou a opção de cadastrar novo usuário, caso seja escolhida, esta opção abre um modal, onde eu cadastro novo Usuário, porem este modal continua aberto, e quando fecho ele, a pagina não está atualizada. Preciso que quando eu fechar ele já atualize a seção para min, e me possibilite ver os usuários novos cadastrados imediatamente.

MEU CODIGO COMPLETO:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#fechar").click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  String lista_Cont = $(this).attr('<?php include "listaUsuario2.php";?>');
                  $("#lista").load(this.lista_Cont);
                });
            });


    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#cadUsuario').submit(function(){
                var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "salvarUsuario.php",
                    data: dados,
                    success: function( data )
                    {
                        alert( data );
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        }); 

</script>
<div class = "conteudo">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div align="left" id="inserir">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Inserir
                        </button>
                    </div>

                                <!-- Listar Usuarios -->
                <legend>Úsuarios Cadastrados</legend>
                <div id="lista">
                <?php include "listaUsuario2.php";?>
                </div>

                </div>
                <!-- Fim listar Usuarios -->

</div> <!-- FECHA CONTEUDO -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Novo Úsuario</h4>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body">            
        <div align="center">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="cadUsuario">
            <fieldset>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="control-group">
                      <label class="control-label" for="TXT_NOMEX_USUAR"></label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <input id="TXT_NOMEX_USUAR" name="TXT_NOMEX_USUAR" type="text" placeholder="Nome" class="input-large">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="control-group">
                      <label class="control-label" for="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL"></label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <input id="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL" name="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="input-xlarge">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Password input-->
                    <div class="control-group">
                      <label class="control-label" for="TXT_SENHA_USUAR"></label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <input id="TXT_SENHA_USUAR" name="TXT_SENHA_USUAR" type="password" placeholder="Senha" class="input-small"> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>          
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="fechar">Fechar</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="botao_cadUsuario">Salvar</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essas linhas não estão nada corretas:

```
String lista_Cont = $(this).attr('<?php include "listaUsuario2.php";?>');
$("#lista").load(this.lista_Cont);
```

Variáveis no javascript são tipadas dinamicamente, não tem como fixar um tipo. Para declarar uma variável localmente, utilize o `var`:

```
var lista_cont = "lista_cont é uma string agora";
```

Se quiser declarar uma propriedade pública de instância, então utilize o `this`:

```
var minhaClasse = function() {
    this.Foo = "Uma string";

    this.imprimeFoo = function() {
        alert(this.Foo);
    }
}

var a = new minhaClasse();
var b = a.Foo;
a.imprimeFoo();
```

Logo, essa linhas tem um problema de sintaxe também, nesse contexto, `this` não existe, pois a variável `lista_cont` foi declarada localmente

```
$("#lista").load(this.lista_Cont); // deveria ser $("#lista").load(lista_Cont);
```

---

**Quanto ao funcionamento do código:**

Não é possível inserir código PHP dessa forma em elementos HTML:

```
$(this).attr('<?php include "listaUsuario2.php";?>');
```

O interpretador do PHP executa no servidor, antes do navegador receber o HTML. Se quiser atualizar dinamicamente com ajax, pode utilizar:

```
$("#lista").load("listaUsuario2.php");
```

O método `load` do PHP carrega o HTML do servidor e o coloca no elemento selecionado.

Comment: Obrigado, pela contribuição.

Comment: pode me ajuda com o deletar ? como faço para manda o id da tabela ?

Comment: Você pode usar o data attribute do elemento que contem o usuário da lista, ao clicar excluir le esse atributo e chama uma função PHP via ajax. No sucesso remove o HTML. Porém sugiro criar uma nova questão com essa dúvida específica, contendo o HTML da sua lista de usuários.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67212/delete-no-banco-utilizando-ajax-e-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Cria uma página com um Select fazendo a busca pelos registros e com a mesma formatação da sua lista.

E no ajax você faz:

```
$("#lista").load('lista.php');

jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "salvarUsuario.php",
   data: dados,
   success: function( data )
   {
       $("#lista").load('listausuario.php');
   }
});
```

Comment: So que tipo, quero fazer isso de forma que so utilize o ajax, e ele carregue esta mesma pagina

Comment: Pode ser a mesma. Desde que seja idêntica sua formatação. Mas não precisa do **include**. O *load* já faz o carregamento da página.

Comment: Ele irá carregar a mesma coisa dentro da minha principal ? Porque esta pagina ja está dentro de uma principal, e se eu atualizo ela volta para home da principal.

Comment: Oh Mano. Você tem uma Div#Lista. Ok ? Dentro dessa Div você carrega um Include pelo que estou vendo. É a lista de Usuários. Beleza. Quando você cadastra alguém novo e fecha o modal você quer recarregar essa lista com a lista nova com o novo usuário cadastrado. Certo ? Então, você pode utilizar a mesma página do Include. Coloca no Load. E coloca um **cache:false** no Ajax.

Comment: Melhor ainda, Cara. Coloca no seu ajax um Success.

Comment: como ficaria  isto ?

Comment: Editei meu Code.

Comment: Obrigado, consiguir obter exito com a sua ajuda. Agora gostaria que me ajuda-se na parte do delete. tem como ?

Comment: Tem sim. Tenta aí alguma coisa e nos fale. Talvez até um tipoco novo.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67212/delete-no-banco-utilizando-ajax-e-jquery

O link de minha outra pergunta.