# Delete no banco utilizando ajax e jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Qual método correto para conseguir deletar, a minha duvida está sendo como pega o id baseado na linha da tabela, e como enviar o mesmo para uma pagina que exclui de fato. Os códigos que já tenho feito estará á seguir.

listaUsuario.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#elemento-pai-da-tabela").on('click', '.btn_Excluir', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var $trPai = $(this).parent().parent(); 
        var id = $trPai.data('id'); 
        $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
            data: { 'COD_IDENT_USUAR': id }, 
            url: "excluirUsuario.php", 
            success: function(msg) { 
                $trPai.remove(); 
            } 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
<?php

    // incluindo o arquivo que faz a conexao com o banco
    include ("../includes/conexao.php");

    // Listando os Cargos

    // executa  query de consulta e armazena o resultado devolvido na variável $resultado
     $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT TXT_NOMEX_USUAR, TXT_ENDER_EMAIL, FLG_STATU_USUAR, DAT_ULTIM_LOGIN, COD_IDENT_USUAR from tbl_USUARIOS");


    // se não existir cargos cadastrados exibe uma mensagem
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultado)<=0)
    {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-error'>";
        echo "<b>Atenção!</b><br>";
        echo "Não existe cargo cadastrado no momento.";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    // se existir produtos cadastrados lista-os
    else
    {
        echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
        echo "<th class='excluir'>Excluir</th>";
        echo "<th class='alterar'>Alterar</th>";
        echo "<th>Nome</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<th>Status</th>";
        echo "<th>Último Login</th>";

        while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
        {
            echo "<tr data-id='$linha[4]'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href='excluirUsuario.php' class='btn_Excluir'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='excluirUsuario.php' class='btn_Alterar'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i></a></td>";
            echo "<td>$linha[0]</td>";
            echo "<td>$linha[1]</td>";
            echo "<td>$linha[2]</td>";
            echo "<td>$linha[3]</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

excluiUsuario.php

```
<?php
     // incluindo o arquivo que faz a conexao com o banco
    include ("../includes/conexao.php");

    // Recebendo o valor enviado pelo link
    $COD_IDENT_USUAR = isset($_POST['COD_IDENT_USUAR']) ? $_POST['COD_IDENT_USUAR'] : '';

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_Usuarios WHERE COD_IDENT_USUAR ='".$COD_IDENT_USUAR."'");

    //fechando a conexao com o banco
    mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Utilizando estes códigos, não estou conseguinte efetuar o delete, ele envia a pagina excluirUsuario.php porem nada acontece.

Comment: `var id = parent.attr('COD_IDENT_USUAR'); ` não devia ser `pai` em vez de `parent`?

Comment: fiz a alterações porem ainda continua indo apenas para a pagina excluiUsuario.php, porem ele não encaminha o id.

Comment: no PHP estás à espera de receber `$_POST['COD_IDENT_USUAR']` mas no JS estás a enviar ` data: "id=" +id, `Acho que deveria ser `data: {id: id},` no JS e `$_POST['id']` no PHP...

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/excluirUsuario.php on line 6

Comment: Onde está no HTML o elemento com atributo `COD_IDENT_USUAR`?

Comment: Ele vem da minha query:

 // executa  query de consulta e armazena o resultado devolvido na variável $resultado
 $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT COD_IDENT_USUAR, TXT_NOMEX_USUAR, TXT_ENDER_EMAIL, FLG_STATU_USUAR, DAT_ULTIM_LOGIN from tbl_USUARIOS");

Comment: Mas onde está a ser inserido no HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Troque

```
<a href='excluirUsuario.php' id='btn_Alterar'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i></a>
```

Por

```
<a href='excluirUsuario.php' id='".$ID_DO_USER."' class='deleta'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i></a>
```

Acima você determina uma classe, porquê serão várias linhas. E o ID do usuário para cada uma no LINK.
Isso é apenas um Pseudo-Code. Ajuste a sua maneira, coloque a variável corretamente do ID no campo ID="".

```
$(".deleta").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var pai = $(this).closest('TR'); 
        var id = this.id; 
        $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
            data: "id=" +id, 
            url: "excluirUsuario.php", 
            success: function(msg){ $('#'+id).fadeOut(300); 
        } 
});
```

Nem vi seu PHP.

Comment: Seu codigo está acusando erro na linha 49, que é:

echo "<td><a href='excluirUsuario.php' id='".$COD_IDENT_USUAR."' class='deleta'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></a></td>";

Comment: Então, por isso que disse pra você colocar corretamente a variável. Porquê eu não entrei muito na parte do HTML do seu code. Mas agora que eu vi apenas tire as aspas duplas e os pontos que envolve a variável. Ficando assim: id='$COD_IDENT_USUAR'

Comment: E além disso no seu Select você deve trazer o nome do campo do ID. E colocar no While igual você fez para os outros campos... Nome...

Comment: Continua da mesma maneira, dando o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, tem que colocar na sua query o ID do usuário, que pelo seu código de delete é `COD_IDENT_USUAR`:

```
 $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT TXT_NOMEX_USUAR, TXT_ENDER_EMAIL, FLG_STATU_USUAR, DAT_ULTIM_LOGIN, COD_IDENT_USUAR from tbl_USUARIOS");
```

Coloque o id lido como data attribute na linha:

```
 while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
 {
    echo "<tr data-id='$linha[4]'>";
```

Há um problema com os botões que você está inserindo nas linhas, não pode usar o mesmo id para todos. Ao invés disso, use uma classe:

```
 echo "<td><a href='excluirUsuario.php' class='btn_Excluir'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></a></td>";
 echo "<td><a href='excluirUsuario.php' class='btn_Alterar'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i></a></td>";
```

Por último, leia o atributo para enviar o parâmetro para o script de exclusão:

```
$("#elemento-pai-da-tabela").on('click', '.btn_Excluir', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var $trPai = $(this).parent().parent(); 
        var id = $trPai.data('id'); 
        $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
            data: { 'COD_IDENT_USUAR': id }, 
            url: "excluirUsuario.php", 
            success: function(msg) { 
                $trPai.remove(); 
            } 
    }); 
});
```

Como criou dinamicamente seus elementos, terá que associar o evento de click em um elemento pai deles (no meu exemplo usei `#elemento-pai-da-tabela`, você não mostrou). Sugiro deixar uma tabela fixa e adicionar as linhas dinamicamente.

Comment: Continua a da o mesmo erro:

   echo "<td><a href='excluirUsuario.php' id='$COD_IDENT_USUAR' class='deleta'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></a></td>";

Comment: Você está usando a solução da outra resposta, tente a minha.

Comment: Ainda está dando um erro aqui o:

// Recebendo o valor enviado pelo link
 $COD_IDENT_USUAR = $_POST['COD_IDENT_USUAR'];

Qual a forma correta de receber um valor ?

Comment: dê uma olhada novamente.